# php if statements how to

Tags: php, switch-statement

So I've looked on various help sites but no one seems to be having the same problem as me, let me explain after my code:

```
    $pgint=$_POST['pg'];

    echo '<li><h4>Insects and Plants</h4>';
    switch($pgint)
    {
    case "1":
    echo '1';
    break;
    case "2":
    echo '2';
    break;
    }
```

It's not echoing anthing, even though "pg" is set to both 1 and 2. Can anyone help? The URL looks like: http://mydomainname.com/index.php?pg=1

not echoing anything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10):

You're confusing POST and GET. You need GET since the value you're looking for is in the querystring:

```
$pgint=$_POST['pg'];
```

should be:

```
$pgint=$_GET['pg'];
```

You should turn [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) up to report all errors including notices. If you did you would have caught this immediately.

Comment: This is why I always use `$_REQUEST` -- it allows the script to be invoked either way.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, pg is a GET variable, not POST.